# How does an app reads an OTP SMS without SMS permission?

Tags: sms, security, permissions, privacy

I have recently installed an Android app from the Play Store.
While registering in it, I realized that it was able to read my message of OTP without even asking for my permission to read the message.

I have AOSP Extended 5.8 with the August security patch.
It's an Android Oreo 8.1 based custom rom.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Verification by OTP uses a different API which doesn't need read SMS permission. You can read more here [Perform SMS Verification on a Server](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify)

Hence, the app isn't reading your SMS but using a separate channel to read specially formatted text messages

I learnt of this when an Xposed module to block permissions did not work as I expected (similar case) and the [developer explained the reason](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=76280804&postcount=2637)

Comment: How it is decided that which app can use api to read which text?
There must be something that prevents X app to read text of Y app by using API's.

Comment: Also, if you read the linked API it talks about hash and coding which means only the authorized app can read